# How to get my # links on my single page site indexed by Google

Tags: seo, javascript, googlebot, google-index, single-page-application

I own a One Page Site. Google is only indexing the home page -> `example.com`.

I tried adding it in Google Webmaster Tools/Search Console how it should be displayed:  `http://example.com/#ueber-desjash-graz`, but it only finds `example.com/index.html`. I think this is because of the JavaScript being used.

Does anyone know what I can do to get my four `#` sections indexed?

Comment: Do you have links to your various sections like `<a href="#ueber-desjash-graz">`?

Comment: yes I use it as my menu

Answer (score 1):

This technique is not the best way in a long run.

Website building platform WIX used to generate similar kind of URL with # and people had difficulty getting it indexed.

You might be lucky if you get it indexed. All I can say is, make sure your page (With #) is completely unique.

If you are serious about your website and ranking then I would recommend you to consider having fully qualified URL like example.com/innerpage-url.html